# Expected Stopping Time of a Discrete Process

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, algorithms

Consider the stochastic process $X: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined as follows:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                  X_1 = 0\\
                  X_{n + 1} = X_n + \mathbf{1}_{\{z_n \leq P_n\}}\\
                  P_n = (X_n + n) / (M + n)
           \end{array}
\right.$$
where $\left(z_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. uniformly distributed over $\left[0, 1\right]$ and $M \in \mathbb{N}^*$ is constant.

Define the stopping time $\tau = \inf \left\{j > 0 \,|\, X_j = M \right\}$.
Then I want to prove that $\mathbb{E}\left[\tau\right] \geq 2M$.

This problem emerges from the analysis of the algorithm "Snow Plow" defined [here](http://didawiki.di.unipi.it/lib/exe/fetch.php/magistraleinformaticanetworking/ae/ae2011/lect3.pdf) by Paolo Ferragina, who unfortunately provides a faulty analysis.